# jQuery function works only on the first element of the foreach in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Basically i am trying to put  a clickable star in each div  in the foreach onclick it changes from black to orange by changing the css class and by clicking again it gets back to black like forever but it only works on the first div in the foreach and this is my style also:

```
         <head>
    <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
.checked {
color: orange;
 }


 img {
  border-radius: 8px;
     }

   .column {
    float: left;
   width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
   height: 550px;
            }


    .column:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
    }
     </style> 
</head>





        @foreach ($posts as $post)


        <div class="column">


          <span  id ="foo" class="fa fa-star" onclick="myFunction1()"></span> 

          <h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
          <img src={{$post->url}}  />


        </div>

        @endforeach

          <script>

       function myFunction1()
    {

    var b = $('#foo').attr('class');
    console.log(b);
    if(b == "fa fa-star")
    {
   document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("class","fa fa-star checked");
    }
    else {
           document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("class","fa fa-star");

          }    

          }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the identifier of the star with a class.

When you use an id, it's to identify a unique specific object.

When you use a class you can apply the same action to all the elements and then just use the specific element.

Something like this:

```html
<div class="column">
    <span class="foo fa fa-star"></span> 
    <h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
    <img src={{$post->url}}  />
</div>
```

And then you just assign this function when someone clicks on a `span.foo` element.

```js
$(".foo").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("checked");
});
```

**EDIT**

In order to check if it's favorite or no you could use the checked class like this:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".foo", function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("checked")) {
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }
});
```

I changed the `$(".foo").click()` to `$(document).on("click", ".foo", ...` in case your elements are generated dynamically, this way the function will affect all elements.

Please check the way you are posting your code here, because it is a little confusing.

**EDIT 2 - Codepen Example**

I created this small example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mi_ov/pen/GRRVWjW) using a structure similar to your code with my adjustments. Please check it.

Comment: i am trying to favorite and unfavorite posts using foreach and it did not work also

Comment: @AhmedHossam I edited my answer, please check your code, because it's a little confusing how you're posting it.

Comment: Also you have to edit the code structure to what I recommended, as if you keep using `<div id="foo">` it won't work.

Comment: @AhmedHossam I added a Codepen Example, open it and click on the stars. I think that's what you're trying to achieve right?

Comment: thank you i will work on it but it still did not  work what could be the problem here?

Comment: Please update your code to the modifications I indicated and update your question with it, because I have no way of knowing what your current code is. The code I showed you on CodePen has to work with what you have.

Comment: i updated it  now it works thank you so much mihail :D

Comment: You can accept the answer then :) Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what you want, but It would be better to remove the id since it is should be unique. You can remove the `onclick` from the spans and do something like this :

```
$("body").on("click", ".foo", function() {
  $(this).addClass("checked");
});
```

Comment: it did not  work  i add my css now  i am trying to favorite and unfavorite posts using foreach